# Angular: Flex doesn't work well on mobile (IOS 13)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am testing a website styled by Flex in CSS. The problem is the website displayed well on the laptop, but not on mobile. Please refer to the image for more detail[image]

Test environment: Chrome/Firefox/Safari, iphone 7, Macbook.

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

P/s: If anyone needs more detail in code, please comment.

#### EDIT

The code:

header.html

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z6 navbar" [ngClass]="{ compact: isHandset | async }">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- <span fxFlex></span> -->
  <span class="title">{{ title }}</span>
  <div>
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu">
      <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
      <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item>
          <b>{{ useremail }}</b>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </mat-list>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()" translate>{{ 'Menu.Logout' | translate }}</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

header.scss

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: $zero;
  left: $zero;
  right: $zero;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: $header-bg;

  @include set-font(
    $header-font-family,
    $header-font-size,
    $header-font-weight,
    $header-font-style,
    $header-text-color
  );

  .logo {
    min-width: $header-logo-width-mobile;
    height: $header-logo-height;
    width: $header-logo-width;
    img {
      width: $w-100;
      height: $h-100;
    }
  }

  .menu-button {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }

  &.compact {
    .logo {
      height: $header-logo-height-mobile;
      width: $header-logo-width-mobile;
    }
  }
}
```

info.html

```
<div class="game-info">
    <div class="team">
      <img  src={{game_info.home_logo}} alt="overlayed img" />
     </div>
  ...
  
  <div class="team">
    <img src= {{game_info.away_logo}} alt="overlayed img" />
    </div>  
</div>
```

info.scss

```
.game-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  .team {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;

    img {
      max-width: 80%;
      max-height: 80%;
    }
  }
  
}
```

I also created a stakblitz to play with:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8tudg

Comment: pls share code..

Comment: could you reproduce your case at [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @Ranjithv Please refer the edit

Comment: @StepUp Please refer the edit

Comment: @francophong there is nothing. Just `Hello Angular! Start editing to see some magic happen :)`

Comment: @francophong Add the following rule to `.team` : `flex: 0 0 auto`, flex-shrink is set to 1 by default and that's why your images are distorted.

Comment: @StepUp https://angular-s8tudg.stackblitz.io (I can only reproduce the image, not the header)

Answer (score 0):

For image deformation problem try adding both `width: XX px;` and `height:XX px;` with some value for mobile size media query `@media` or vice versa in large screen.

For header problem try adding the `z-index: 1000;` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to the header container and flex-container in a row. it may help.